# Regular Expressions For skype name in PHP

Tags: php, regex

Please I want to validate the skype name using regular expressions in PHP.

**NOTE:** It must be between 6-32 characters, start with a letter and contain only letters and numbers (no spaces or special characters).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This pattern should work for you:

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\.,\-_]{5,31}
```

This will match a leading letter, followed by any alpha-numeric combination up to a total of between 6 - 32 characters (for the entire string).

You can use this in PHP with:

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-z][a-z0-9\.,\-_]{5,31}$/i', $name)) {
    // you have a valid name!
}
```

Note, in the `preg_match()`, I added the `i` regex option to ignore case. Also, I lead the pattern with `^` to signify that the pattern has to start at the *beginning* of the string and I ended with a `$` to signify that the pattern has to finish at the *end* of the string.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job:

```
preg_match( '~^[a-z][a-z0-9]{5,31}$~i', $text)
```